# Solving an equation with an inexact parameter

Tags: equation-solving, numerics

`Solve` was unable to solve the system with inexact coefficients or the system obtained by direct rationalization of inexact numbers present in the system. Since many of the methods used by `Solve` require exact input, providing `Solve` with an exact version of the system may help.

```
Solve[R - (20 (1 - (1 - exp[-0.692 R])^5))/exp[-0.692 R] == 0, R]
```

Comment: `Solve[R - (20 (1 - (1 - Exp[-0.692 R])^5))/Exp[-0.692 R] == 
  0, R, Reals]` says R->100. Same answer for NSolve.

Comment: Also, you used "exp" when you need to use "Exp[ ]". Got to capitalize the 'E'.

Comment: note 100 is the exact limit solution as `-k->Infinity`, which is to say the solution to this problem is not "exactly" 100. You might do a second order series expansion if you wanted to chase that down.